# About creating a new project in GitHub

Tags: github

Kinda new to GitHub, I want to create a repository for my open-source project.

If my username is Bob, the link would be like https://github.com/bob/my-project

And you could visit my personal profile at https://github.com/bob

However, I have seen projects like this: https://github.com/ruby/ruby

My guess was: *well, it means that there is some user called "ruby" who has a repository called "ruby"*.

So naturally, I could see this "ruby" user's personal profile at https://github.com/ruby... But you can tell that's NOT a normal profile. Instead, it is some sort of list for related repositories.

Well then, what is that? Am I supposed to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an organisation. https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations

On Github you can create organisations to organize members and repositories.

Answer (score 2):

That is a [GitHub organization](https://help.github.com/categories/2/articles).